# Frequency Determination of Audio Signal in Python

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I have an audio signal which has tones of different frequencies and these tones are seperated by a silence. I have to extract those tones and then find the frequency using fft and converting into **Hertz** of that tones and save them in an array.

I want to use scipy, numpy for fft computation. The below is a code that I am trying out. Not sure if I'm on the right path.

Any suggestion on how to proceed would be helpful or any alternative idea of yours would be appreciated.

```
import wave
import struct
import numpy as np

sound_file = wave.open('Audio_1.wav', 'r') ## Open Audio file
file_length = sound_file.getnframes() ## Find number of frames
print file_length
sound = np.zeros(file_length)
for i in range(file_length):
    data = sound_file.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("<h", data)
    sound[i] = int(data[0])
sound = np.divide(sound, float(2**15))
print sound
Ap = np.pad(sound, (0,int(np.ceil(len(sound) / 11874.)) * 11874 - len(sound)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
Apr = Ap.reshape((len(Ap) // 11874, 11874))
print Apr
Apr.shape
print Apr.shape
array1=(Apr ** 2).sum(axis=1)
print array1
#print len(array1)
threshold =4700
result= np.array(filter(lambda x: x>= threshold, array1))
print result 

print len(result)
print np.where(array1>4700)
#print array1.shape
#print result.shape
#print sound.shape
#print Apr.shape
#fftoutput=np.fft.fft(result)
#print fftoutput
#print np.argsort(fftoutput)
```

Comment: I was doing something similar a long time ago. It might help to take a look at my [code](https://github.com/praveenv253/tuner/blob/master/tuner.py), to get some clues.